# setting variable with eval in Makefile recipe

Tags: makefile, eval

I was looking at another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38227975/when-should-a-call-to-eval-be-evaluated-in-a-make-recipe), and they were using, what looks to be undocumented behavior for makefiles...   If I have the following Makefile:

```
X=X 

all:
    @echo $@: $(X)
    $(eval X=Y)
    @echo $@ part2: $(X)

all2:
    @echo $@: $(X)
```

Then I run:

```
~> make all2
all2: X
~> make all all2
running all
all: X
all part2: Y
all2: Y
```

I would have expected the `$(eval X=Y)` to expand at Makefile parse time, and set the *shell* variable `X` to be `Y` for that line of the recipe (i.e. do nothing).  Instead, it seems to be evaluated when the `all` recipe is run, plus, it seems to set the make variable.    I've looked through the make man page, and for online manuals, but I can't find anything that describes this behavior (I'm using GNU Make 4.0).   Can someone point me to some documentation describing this, or explain what's going on?

Comment: You may find more information here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224102/make-define-multiple-variables-in-the-same-eval-call .
Basically, as said in the GNU make documentation, it's a Makefile syntax part evaluated at the call so it's still a Makefile variable and it is, indeed, evaluated in the target `all` . Here's `eval` documentation : https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why you would expect either of the things you mention to be true.  Maybe you're thinking that this is using the shell `eval`, somehow?  That's not what it's doing, it's using the GNU make `eval` function, which is [discussed here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html).

Just like any other variable or function, `eval` appearing in a recipe is not expanded until (and unless) the recipe is invoked because the target is out of date.  See [How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html) for full details on when variables and functions are expanded.

Second, all make variable assignments set make variables, and only if you `export` them will they be sent to the shell.